# Magento products depending on country of delivery

Tags: magento-1.9, product, collection, delivery

I'm just starting exploring Magento, to update our current site.
One of the requirements is that the displayed catalog, is depending on the country of delivery. Not all products can be shipped to specific countries.

On our current site's homepage, we have a popup asking the country of delivery. That way we know the correct productlist to display.

How is this done in Magento?

Answer (score 1):

Technically you need a website per county but you will destroy the performance at 15-20 websites. The coding method is very unstable as there are parts all over the core which you would need to adjust, on a business level it will not work. Magento is not designed for this, yes we have this functionality but it's not transferable, it's part of an architecture.

Answer (score 0):

### It Possible but you need to customize the Custom module and save product and it respective Country

First create [custom  module with a table](http://www.amitbera.com/create-an-magento-extension-with-custom-database-table/) which is save product id and it  respective country.

Table should contain three `columns pk,product_id,country_id`.
[image]

### 2.Filter Collection by event on frontend

Then you using [magento event & observer](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method) filter the collection on  frontend on

**Event:** `catalog_product_collection_load_after` yon can filter product collection by country.

```
<frontend>
<events>
    <catalog_product_collection_load_after>
    <observers>
        <countryfilter>
        <class>mymoduleMOdelprefix/observer</class>
        <method>filterBYCountry</method>
        </countryfilter>
    </observers>
    </catalog_product_collection_load_after>
</frontend>
```

### Observer code where collection is filtered:

```
<?php class MyNamespacr_Mymodule_Model_Observer
    public function filterBYCountry($observer)
    {
        $collection = $observer->getEvent()->getCollection();
        /* @var $collection Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Collection */
        /* d here join with your atble
        return $this;
    }
```